# Order of a conjugate permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

From Finan:

Let $\sigma\in{S_n}$, define the $\mathbf{order}$ of $\sigma$ to be the smallest positive integer such that $\sigma^m=(1)$.  Prove that if $\sigma$ has order $m$ then $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$ has order $m$ for all $\tau\in{S_n}$.

So $\tau$ can have its own order, so let $order(\tau)=p$.  Thus $\tau^p=(1)$.  If $(m,p)=1$, then $order(\tau\sigma)=mp$.  But doesn't $order(\tau^{-1})=p$?  Thus $order(\tau\sigma\tau^{-1})=pmp$.  So them this implies $(\tau\sigma\tau^{-1})^{pmp}$...  Not sure where to go with this.

Comment: Remark: This has nothing to do with permutations. It holds in every group. Hint for abstract solution: Automorphisms preserve the order of an element.

Comment: So if I have $\varphi:S_n\rightarrow{S_n}$ such that $\varphi(\sigma)=\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$, for all $\tau\in{S_n}$, that's all I need I that since this is an automorphism, $order(\tau\sigma\tau^{-1})=m$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418761/order-of-permutation-if-tau-in-s-n-has-order-m-then-sigma-tau-sigma?rq=1

Comment: Perfect.  I'll duplicate the question.